# Why gradle 3.2.1 generate unnecessary/duplicated empty folder in aar file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

environment: android studio 3.3
             gradle 3.2.1
When build library proejct using with gradle 3.2.1(android studio 3.3) 
aar file include empty folder at root directory like below image.

[image]

I think that folders unnecessary because that files exist real file in jni folder or res folder.
Is that structure is right?
So how can I exclude that folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those folders are for mipmap drawables and for architecture specific build artifacts. Here are other files and directories that could be included (https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#aar-contents):

```
/AndroidManifest.xml
/classes.jar
/res/
/R.txt
/public.txt
```

Additionally, an AAR file may include one or more of the following optional entries:

```
/assets/
/libs/name.jar
/jni/abi_name/name.so (where abi_name is one of the Android supported ABIs)
/proguard.txt
/lint.jar
```

Comment: I agree that folders(red squere box)  include in aar file.
but those folders are empty folder and duplicated
the real file(folder) exist under '/res/' or '/jni/ ' directory

Comment: @김종선 it is how the zip (aar) is getting created. It is probably just zipping up the top level folder. Since the folders are empty is does not matter either way.

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I exclude that folders?

Try this

```
android {
...
packagingOptions {
    exclude "mipmap**"
}
...
}
```

Comment: My only concern here is excluding folders that the build system creates that do not cause errors of any kind. If they do get filled in the future, then this would exclude them and someone might not realize it. Esp with the architecture folders.